# Character set warning in PXC logs

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, percona, galera

I am using PXC 5.6 (Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-56-5.6.41-28.28.1.el7.x86_64) and my log file is flooded with this warning:

> [Warning] Client failed to provide its character set. 'latin1' will be
>   used as client character set.

how can I disable this warning or at least set character by default?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though this is related to a MySQL bug, here is one discussion https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/mysql-and-percona-server/13590-character-set-warning

Here is the bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72543

A poster on StackOverflow reported that after updating the connector the issue was resolved, might this apply here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...ws-server-2012

If you are using HA Proxy, this may also be relevant, and there is a workaround at the end: https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-1518